# Sharepoint team site is only available on server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sharepoint-2013

I've installed sharepoint 2013 on windows server 2008 and I've made a team site , but the team site is only available on the server , I mean when I logon to team site from another computer using web browser and the administrator user , everything is OK and I have access to all administration tools , but the team site is not accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Did you publish the URL in DNS?

If you have host settings on server or it's being accessed via the servername locally that would explain why that works there and not from a client machines.